# Problem after packages upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, radeon, cryptsetup

This morning I upgraded the following packages:

`libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4.1), libguestfs-hfsplus:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1), liblvm2cmd2.02:amd64 (2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4, 2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4.1), dmsetup:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4.1), libdevmapper-event1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4.1), libguestfs0:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1), dmeventd:amd64 (2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4, 2:1.02.145-4.1ubuntu4.1), lvm2:amd64 (2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4, 2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4.1), libguestfs-perl:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1), libguestfs-tools:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1), libguestfs-reiserfs:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1), liblvm2app2.2:amd64 (2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4, 2.02.176-4.1ubuntu4.1), libguestfs-xfs:amd64 (1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1, 1:1.40.2-1ubuntu1.1)`

Then when generating the initram-fs I got the following message:

`update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-16-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: The initramfs image may not contain cryptsetup binaries nor crypto modules. If that's on purpose, you may want to uninstall the 'cryptsetup-initramfs' package in order to disable the cryptsetup initramfs integration and avoid this warning.
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu`

Until this last upgrade I had no such warning messages.

My hardware (Dell Inspiron 5567) is:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U @ 2.70GHz

Integrated GPU: Intel Graphics HD620

Secondary GPU: ATI Radeon R7 M440

System: Ubuntu 19.04 on kernel 5.0.0-16-generic.

How do I fix, if possible, the warnings?